# Oxyplot excepttion while creating a model with bar series

Tags: android, xamarin, oxyplot

I am using the OxyPlot view to show some data in a diagram. It has been working correctly until yesterday. Since, I added the database part (sqlite) to my application, whenever I open the activity page included OxyPlot, it just shows this message on the mobile screen:

> Oxyplot excepttion: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object. an exception of type system.NullReferenceException was thrown
>   at Oxyplot.ReflectionPath..ctor(System.String path)[0x00006]

I tried to find where it has happened by putting a breakpoint when a `System.NullReferenceException` was thrown but the program was not stopped.

Adding a `PlotView` control to the user interface in my activity:

```
design d = new design();

var plotView = new PlotView(this);

plotView.Model = d.CreatePlotModelTest;
this.AddContentView(plotView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent));
```

UPDATED:

I noticed, if I use a linear series while creating the plot model instead of bar series, the error will disappear. But, if I try a bar series(in the code below, you can see as it is commented), the app will show me the error again.

```
public PlotModel CreatePlotModelTest()
    {
        var plotModel = new PlotModel { Title = "OxyPlot Demo" };

        plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom });
        plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left, Maximum = 10, Minimum = 0 });


        var series1 = new LineSeries
        {
            MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
            MarkerSize = 4,
            MarkerStroke = OxyColors.White
        };

        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0.0, 6.0));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1.4, 2.1));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2.0, 4.2));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3.3, 2.3));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(4.7, 7.4));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(6.0, 6.2));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(8.9, 8.9));

        plotModel.Series.Add(series1);

        /*var barSeries = new BarSeries
        {
            ItemsSource = new List<BarItem>(new[]
    {
            new BarItem{ Value = (2) },
            new BarItem{ Value = (3) },
            new BarItem{ Value = (4) },
            new BarItem{ Value = (5) },
            new BarItem{ Value = (6) }
    }),
            LabelPlacement = LabelPlacement.Inside,
            LabelFormatString = "{2:0.0}"
        };
        plotModel.Series.Add(barSeries);

        plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom });
            plotModel.Axes.Add(new CategoryAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Left,
                Key = "CakeAxis",
                ItemsSource = new[]
                    {
            "Apple cake",
            "Baumkuchen",
            "Bundt Cake",
            "Chocolate cake",
            "Carrot cake"
    }
            });*/

        return plotModel;
    }
```

Anyone has an idea what can be the problem of creating my model with bar series?

Comment: At which line are you getting error?

Comment: This is my problem, I put a breakpoint, but actually VS doesn't show me at which line I am getting the error.

Comment: What is `energyBarsList`  and `PlotView` ? Show `PlotView` class if it is created by you.

Comment: The exception location is shown: It is in the constructor: `Oxyplot.ReflectionPath..ctor`

Comment: Maybe the debugger doesn't stop because you are putting the breakpoint after the exception. Also as @ShushiHangover said, you have the location. I bet for the constructors like `new PlotView(..)` and `new PlotModel(..)`.

Comment: Try to first create an empty BarSeries, and then populate it with BarItems, instead of doing it on the constructor. Just like you do it with your LineSeries.

Comment: Thanks Jose, yes I already tried that and it works. Actually, I noticed since I've added database (SQLLinq) to my application, this error started to happen. So, I am trying to use async task in odrer to solve it. If it works, I will write the result here.

Comment: @gleng Hi, thanks but I did not try it. I posted my solution on the first answer and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

If I write create plotModel like this, it works well:

```
public PlotModel CreatePlotModelTest()
    {
        var model = new PlotModel
        {
            Title = "BarSeries",
            LegendPlacement = LegendPlacement.Outside,
            LegendPosition = LegendPosition.BottomCenter,
            LegendOrientation = LegendOrientation.Horizontal,
            LegendBorderThickness = 0
        };


        var rand = new Random();
        double[] cakePopularity = new double[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            cakePopularity[i] = rand.NextDouble();
        }
        var sum = cakePopularity.Sum();

        var s2 = new BarSeries { Title = "Series 1", StrokeColor = OxyColors.Black, StrokeThickness = 1 };
        s2.Items.Add(new BarItem { Value = (cakePopularity[0] / sum * 100) });
        s2.Items.Add(new BarItem { Value = (cakePopularity[1] / sum * 100) });
        s2.Items.Add(new BarItem { Value = (cakePopularity[2] / sum * 100) });
        s2.Items.Add(new BarItem { Value = (cakePopularity[3] / sum * 100) });
        s2.Items.Add(new BarItem { Value = (cakePopularity[4] / sum * 100) });

        var categoryAxis = new CategoryAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left };
        categoryAxis.Labels.Add("Apple cake");
        categoryAxis.Labels.Add("Baumkuchen");
        categoryAxis.Labels.Add("Bundt Cake");
        categoryAxis.Labels.Add("Chocolate cake");
        categoryAxis.Labels.Add("Carrot cake");
        var valueAxis = new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, MinimumPadding = 0, MaximumPadding = 0.06, AbsoluteMinimum = 0 };
        model.Series.Add(s2);
        //model.Series.Add(s2);
        model.Axes.Add(categoryAxis);
        model.Axes.Add(valueAxis);

        return model;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caused by this line:

```
LabelFormatString = "{2:0.0}",
```

as this in invalid. I believe you are looking for this:

```
LabelFormatString = "{#:0.0}",
```